# Drawing circle of variable radius using mouse in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, drawing

My question is with reference to [this tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html#more-advanced-demo).
In the above tutorial, whenever we drag the mouse pointer, a circle of constant radius (ie. 5 pixels) is drawn.

I want to draw a circle, having radius equal to the distance dragged by mouse left click. Also want to show the preview when the mouse pointer is being moved after Left Button is down. Similar to what happens in MS Paint.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing=False
mode=True   # True--> Rectangle , False --> Circle

ix,iy=-1,-1

def draw_fig(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing,mode,img

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing=True
        ix,iy=x,y
        if(not mode):#ie. Drawing Mode==Circle
            backup=img

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (drawing):
            if(mode):
                cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(255,0,0),-1)
            else:
                #Resetting Canvas
                #img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
                #cv2.putText(img,'Sankalp',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
                #Showing Circle Preview
                cv2.circle(backup,(x,y),max(abs(ix-x),abs(iy-y)),(0,0,255),-1)

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        if(drawing):
            drawing=False
            if(mode):
                cv2.rectangle(img,(ix,iy),(x,y),(255,0,0),-1)
            else:
                #Resetting Canvas
                img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
                cv2.putText(img,'Sankalp',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
                #Showing Circle Preview
                cv2.circle(backup,(x,y),max(abs(ix-x),abs(iy-y)),(0,0,255),-1)
                img=backup

img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_fig)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img,'Sankalp',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(1)
    if(k==ord('m')):
        mode=not mode
    elif k==27:
        break
    elif k==ord('r'):
        img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.uint8)
        cv2.putText(img,'Sankalp',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But its showing me an error :

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'backup' referenced before
>   assignment

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: `backup` is not initialized in both `elif` blocks.